# openCV: The function is not implemented

Tags: python, opencv, centos

Trying to run a python script and it throws the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the
 library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or 
 Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure
 script) in cvDestroyAllWindows, file /io/opencv/modules/highgui
 /src/window.cpp, line 577
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ldsvm/PycharmProjects/tagging/C1_DrawBboxesOnImages.py", line 
  116, in <module> cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.error: /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:577: error: (-2) The 
 function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or 
 Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and 
 pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function  
 cvDestroyAllWindows
```

I have installed the `libgtk2.0-dev` and `pkg-config` and reinstalled `opencv3` but still get the same error.

I am on CentOS.

Comment: A quick (maybe not safe) fix is to delete `destroyAllWindows` from your code. All `opencv` windows will be closed when your main exits anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to remove the opencv packages update your conda and then find the missing package using third command.

```
conda remove opencv
conda update conda
conda install --channel menpo opencv
```

Another option is instead of using opencv built-in function use **matplotlib** for this....

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('img.jpg',0)

plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Comment: MacOS and Linux wheels have currently some limitations:

video related functionality is not supported (not compiled with FFmpeg)
for example cv2.imshow() will not work (not compiled with GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support)

Answer (score 0):

just uninstall *opencv-python-headless* that should fix the problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).